# What is dotnet host version?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

When i run `dotnet --info` in the output i get host version: 3.0.3 
What is it?

[image]

Recently i have installed and later deleted dotnet sdk 3.0 version, but host version is still 3.0.3 does it affect running my program in 2.2 version of sdk?

Comment: Please clarify anybody!!! Having same query.....

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70463595/what-is-the-meaning-of-host-useful-for-support-in-output-of-dotnet-info