# What is the meaning of 'Host (useful for support)' in output of 'dotnet --info'

Tags: .net-core

Output from `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.416
 Commit:    8d3765c609

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.13
  Commit:  b3afe99225

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.416 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.404 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

What does 'Host (useful for support) Version 5.0.13' mean here?
I have a global.json to specify that I want to use 3.1.416:

global.json:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "3.1.416",
        "rollForward": "disable"
    }
}
```

But this 'Host (useful for support)' seems to indicate that I am using 5.0.13 after all.

Answer (score 3):

So, you already knew that on a single machine multiple .NET Core SDK can be installed, like 3.1 and 5.0 on yours.

They both install to a common place `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk`, but there is a single `dotnet.exe` executable, which usually comes from the newest .NET Core SDK installation, which is the "Host" in your context.

When you set the desired SDK version in `global.json`, the 5.0 Host is smart enough to redirect all actual commands (like `dotnet build`) to utilize the 3.1 SDK bits.