# How can dotnet core 5 be so slow on simplest console app?

Tags: .net-core

I am on Windows 10, I had dotnet core 3.1, but I also have now dotnet core 5, apparently from an update. I noticed that dotnet applications ran more slowly, e.g.:
I open PowerShell in a new map, and do:

```
dotnet new console
dotnet build
measure-command { dotnet run }
```

I get this output:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 10
Milliseconds      : 617
Ticks             : 106172423
TotalDays         : 0.000122884748842593
TotalHours        : 0.00294923397222222
TotalMinutes      : 0.176954038333333
TotalSeconds      : 10.6172423
TotalMilliseconds : 10617.2423
```

10 seconds seems slow.

I re-installed dotnet core 3.1

If I open a new map, first add a global.json like this:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "3.1.416",
        "rollForward": "disable"
    }
}
```

and then do the same commands, I still get about 10 seconds. How can this be so slow?

`dotnet --info` says:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.416
 Commit:    8d3765c609

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.13
  Commit:  b3afe99225

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.416 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.404 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

According to this answer:
[What is the meaning of 'Host (useful for support)' in output of 'dotnet --info'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70463595/what-is-the-meaning-of-host-useful-for-support-in-output-of-dotnet-info)
the dotnet.exe is from version 5, but it should be smart enough to behave like 3.1.

What can I do about this?

Update:
Problems are probably caused because my CPU is behaving badly. I used  ([CPU-Z](https://valid.x86.fr/bench/1)) benchmark to compare.
[cpu comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKO8w.png)
So I need to repare that first.

Comment: If it's freshly installed runtime it may need to download necessary nugets. After first run it should build faster. Also you can use `dotnet run --no-build` to skip building and immediately run application without additional checks

Comment: I've seen your answer about the CPU throttling, but that's not what I want to comment. Your measure-command is measuring both the time dotnet SDK tools takes to analyze the project and check if it needs to be built, and then to locate the executable, in addition to executing the actual executable. If you want to measure the performance of your *code* only, you would need to navigate into the bin folder and measure only the executable, something like `measure-command { bin\Debug\net5.0\yourapp.exe }`

Answer (score 1):

Update:
It was the CPU. It was running at 25% because it was incorrectly sensing a high temperature and went to a save operating mode.

Solution: Turn off the laptop, remove the battery, wait for some time.